# this-> in void public functions

Tags: c++, arduino

Arduino library made public on github, there's an inconsistency with his this-> I'm not sure I understand. I'm wondering if the this->prev_milliseconds is needed in most cases he used them.

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif
#include "Metro.h"

Metro::Metro()
{

this->interval_millis = 1000;

}


Metro::Metro(unsigned long interval_millis)
{

this->interval_millis = interval_millis;

}


void Metro::interval(unsigned long interval_millis)
{
  this->interval_millis = interval_millis;
}

uint8_t Metro::check()
{

  unsigned long now = millis();

  if ( interval_millis == 0 ){
    previous_millis = now;
return 1;
  }

  if ( (now - previous_millis) >= interval_millis) {
#ifdef NOCATCH-UP
previous_millis = now ;
#else
previous_millis += interval_millis ;
#endif
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;

}

void Metro::reset()
{

  this->previous_millis = millis();

}
```

More precisely, I don't see the need for this-> in reset() or why there's none in the function above.

```
void Metro::reset()
{

  this->previous_millis = millis();

}
```

What am I forgetting or overseeing? Or what is he doing wrong? (doubtful considering where I took this from.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `this` *can* be used implicitly in this condition. It can also be used explicitly as it is being done in the code you showed.

In this situation, this code:

```
void Metro::reset() {
  this->previous_millis = millis();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void Metro::reset() {
  previous_millis = millis(); // this-> will be resolved implicitly by the compiler
}
```

However, note that in this sample, the member will **not** be changed, only the local variable.

```
void Metro::reset() {
  unsigned long previous_millis;
  previous_millis = millis(); // will assign to local variable
  this->previous_millis = millis(); // will assign to class member
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the need for it in the constructor(unsigned long) but the other one didn't make sense since he obviously knows he didn't need it in the function just above. Weird stuff. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user3299912 You say thanks, but did not accept the answer.  Is there something else you where looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No, isn't needed there, this is used to refer to certain property of the object, and it's needed you have another variable with the same name. As you have in most of the methods, but not in the Reset one.